# Getting a php array

Tags: php, api, curl

I need to interpret the array received from a remote licensing.
I am calling the remote api via curl and the answer in the browser is:

The parsed answer from curl done by using:

```
parse_str(curl_exec($ch), $parsed);
print_r($parsed);
```

**is exactly as here:**

```
Array ( [{"success":true,"uses":154,"purchase":{"id":"GYFt6sW7hbURSVdSpipb5g] => =","created_at":"2015-06-06T16:44:41Z","email":"askolon11@gmail.com","full_name":"daniel","variants":"","custom_fields":[],"product_name":"Direkt 1.2","subscription_cancelled_at":null,"subscription_failed_at":null}} )
```

I tried already for several hours to get the "success" item so later on to check it if it is true or false.

I used

```
 while (list($var, $val) = each($parsed)) {
      print "$var is $val\n";
    }
```

but the result is the same.

Also I tried:

```
$parsed[0]['success'] or $parsed[0]['success']
```

and no result as well.

My full code is:

```
<?php $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.gumroad.com/v2/licenses/verify");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$data = array(    'product_permalink' => 'skQsA',    'license_key' => 'AB26AD9D-1B3B42E0-92356540-CF4E7C1B'  );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);


$output  = array();

parse_str(curl_exec($ch), $parsed);
print_r($parsed); // HERE WE HAVE THE ARRAY 


 while (list($var, $val) = each($parsed)) {
      //  print "$var is $val\n";
    }


curl_close($ch);
```

?>

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `print_r` can you show what `var_dump($parsed);` will output. ?

Comment: Here it is:


array(1) { ["{"success":true,"uses":262,"purchase":{"id":"GYFt6sW7hbURSVdSpipb5g"]=> string(230) "=","created_at":"2015-06-06T16:44:41Z","email":"email@gmail.com","full_name":"daniel","variants":"","custom_fields":[],"product_name":"Direct","subscription_cancelled_at":null,"subscription_failed_at":null}}" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API seems to return a JSON encoded string. So instead of:

```
parse_str(curl_exec($ch), $parsed);
```

use:

```
$parsed = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
```

Then a `print_r($parsed)` will output:

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [uses] => 154
    ...
)
```

And for checking success value:

```
if ($parsed['success']) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just did it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

`$parsed[0]['success'];`

try just

`$parsed['success'];`

If the array you are getting back is an associative array, then the 'key' will be the word 'success'.

```
$parsed = [
  "success" => true,
  "uses" => 154,
  "purchase" => 
      [
      "id" => "GYFt6sW7hbURSVdSpipb5g] => =",
      "created_at" => "2015-06-06T16:44:41Z",
      "email" => "askolon11@gmail.com",
      "full_name" => "daniel",
      "variants" => "",
      "custom_fields" => [],
      "product_name" => "Direkt 1.2",
      "subscription_cancelled_at" => null,
      "subscription_failed_at" => null
  ]];


if($parsed['success'])
    echo 'true';
else
    echo 'false';
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir but:

$parsed['success'], it shows nothing

Better If I can manipulate this way for instance

If I use 

if($parsed['success'] == 'true')

        //code to be done
    else
      // code to be done